How to insert a specific variable into the log formatter, avoiding the usual extra parameter?
How to drag any parameter into logging.Formatter?
Imagine that you have several threads that execute some code, and each of them writes logs. This includes calling the code of important third-party libraries, the files of which only contain import logging..
I'd like to have some way to say "all log messages in this function call (including child calls) will contain a task_id which I also pass to the function". So something like this:
*** boo.py *** 
import logging

def fn():
    logging.debug('Some module debug message')
    logging.info('Some module info message')

*** main.py *** 
import logging
import boo

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(fooid)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('app.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)


def foo(foo_id: str):
    logging.trace_magic(foo_id)

    logger.debug('Debug message')
    logger.info('Info message')
    logger.warning('Warning message')
    logger.error('Error message')
    logger.critical('Critical message')

    boo.fn()

foo('test run')

To have something like this as an output
2024-04-12 19:05:49,792 - test run - DEBUG - Debug message
2024-04-12 19:05:49,792 - test run - INFO - Info message
2024-04-12 19:05:49,792 - test run - WARNING - Warning message
2024-04-12 19:05:49,792 - test run - ERROR - Error message
2024-04-12 19:05:49,792 - test run - CRITICAL - Critical message
2024-04-12 19:05:49,792 - test run - DEBUG - Some module debug message
2024-04-12 19:05:49,792 - test run - INFO - Some module info message



Does this answer your question? set default logging extra for python's Logger object
